# TinyMCE file_picker_callback select image server directory of already uploaded images

Tags: tinymce, filechooser, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5, imagepicker

I already have working script for uploading new images to the server which I access via:
INSERT > IMAGE > UPLOAD

however, sometimes I need to use image which I uploaded already, therefore Im looking for some file_picker_callback() script which would let me browse in the selected directory on the server (not hdd of user) where I upload images and let me choose the one I wish.

I havent find out any of the script which would do that, so I was hoping someone can point me out for anything free to use.

I load it like this:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#mytextarea",
        language: "en",
        plugins: "wordcount autolink link preview charmap directionality fullscreen emoticons media paste save spellchecker table searchreplace visualblocks quickbars image imagetool moxiemanager",
        menubar: "file edit view insert format table tools",

        image_advtab: true,
        paste_data_images: true,

        default_link_target: "_blank",
        automatic_uploads: true,
        file_picker_types: 'image',

        relative_urls: false,
        remove_script_host: false,
        document_base_url: "http://www.somehost.com/",
        images_upload_url: '../uploadChecker.php',
        images_upload_credentials: true,

        file_picker_callback: function(callback, value, meta) {
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you resolve this issue @Jiri Zaloudek?

Comment: unfortunately not yet

Comment: Thanks @Jiri Zaloudek. I did use SunEditor. You can try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to achieve this by creating a page to display all image files on the server and then use [custom URL dialog](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/urldialog) to open that page. The external page will send image URL back to TinyMCE through browsers' `window.postMessage` API. The URL dialogue will use `onMessage` event listener to catch the image URL and pass it to the image dialogue through `callback()`  in [file_picker_callback](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/image/#file_picker_callback).

This is my file_picker_callback function:

```
file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
        var fileBrowseUrl =  "images.html"; //external page
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.openUrl({
          url: fileBrowseUrl,
          title: 'Server File Browser',
          width: 800,
          height: 600,
          resizable: "yes",
          onMessage: function (api, data) {
            callback(data.src, {alt: data.alt});
          }
```

This is the jQuery script in the external page "imges.html" that listens to click events on images and send image URL and alt text back to the URL dialogue:

```
$('body').on('click', 'img', function (e) {
                var imgSrc = $(this).prop('src');
                var imgAlt = $(this).prop('alt');
                //send image url back to TinyMce
                window.parent.postMessage({
                    mceAction: 'customAction',
                    src: imgSrc,
                    alt: imgAlt
                });
                //close external page and return to TinyMce
                window.parent.postMessage({
                    mceAction: 'close'
                });
            });
```

Demo codes can be find here: https://github.com/jeffhehe/TinyMce-file-picker-callback-demo